# Stop looping at the end of a document

Tags: vba, loops, ms-word

I am programming a macro in VBA for MS Word to copy highlighted terms and paste them into another document. The problem is that I cannot stop the loop at the end of the document, and it continues the search from the beginning of the document and never stops.

Could someone help me please?

Here is the code of the macro:

```
  Sub gethigh()
  '
  ' gethigh Macro
  '

  MsgBox ("Before processing the file, this macro is going to save it as: << sourcedoc.doc >> and to create another document called: << targetdoc.doc >> and will then perform the export. Click OK to continue.")

  ActiveDocument.SaveAs ("sourcedoc.doc")
  Documents.Add

  ActiveDocument.SaveAs "targetdoc.doc"
  Documents("sourcedoc.doc").Activate
  Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToLine, Which:=wdGoToFirst
  Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
  Do
      Selection.Find.Highlight = True
      With Selection.Find
          .Text = ""
          .Replacement.Text = ""
          .Forward = True
          .Wrap = wdFindContinue
          .Format = True
      End With
      Selection.Find.Execute
      Selection.Copy
      Documents("targetdoc.doc").Activate
      Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToLine, Which:=wdGoToLast
      Selection.PasteAndFormat wdPasteDefault
      Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
      Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdLineBreak
      Documents("sourcedoc.doc").Activate
  Loop
  Documents("targetdoc.doc").Activate
  Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
  Selection.Find.Highlight = True
  Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
  Selection.Find.Replacement.Highlight = False
  With Selection.Find
      .Text = ""
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = True
  End With
  Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  Documents.Save noprompt:=True
  MsgBox "Processing is complete."
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the problem:

```
.Wrap = wdFindContinue
```

This tells it to continue again from the beginning.